# get single occurrence of 'parent id' in self join

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have table with following set of data :

```
CategoryId  CategoryName    ParentCategoryId
1             abc                       null
2             abc1                      1
3             abc2                      1
4             def                       null
5             def1                      4
6             def2                      4
7             ghi                       null
8             ghi1                      7
9             ghi2                      7
```

I used self join on this table with the following query :

```
select p.CategoryId as ParentCategoryId, p.CategoryName as ParentCategoryName,
       c.CategoryId as CategoryId, c.CategoryName as CategoryName 
from Categories c, Categories p
where c.ParentCategoryId = p.CategoryId
```

This query produces duplicate rows of parent category id and name for every categoryid.

I want that PraentCategoryId to appear one time for all its respective subcategories.

What I need to do further or is there a way to modify this query.

the result of above query is like

```
ParentCategoryId    ParentCategoryName  CategoryId  CategoryName
    1             abc                       2        abc1
    1             abc                       3        abc2
    4             def                       5        def1
    4             def                       6        def2
    7             ghi                       8        ghi1
    7             ghi                       9        ghi2
```

Comment: Please join the 21st century and stop using commas in the `FROM` clause.  Also, tag your question with the database you are really using.  I removed the competing database tags.  And, I see no duplicates in the result set.

Comment: @GordonLinoff can you please reformat the query so I know what can be used in place of comma in `FROM` clause. Also I've provided the output of the query. The parentcategoryId is occurring two times. How can I change it to single occurrence.

Comment: You are getting 2 rows because there are 2 child categories. How are you wanting the child categories displayed?

Answer (score 0):

I've put two versions of the query using JOINs. The first will show each parent with each child on their own rows. The second uses GROUP_CONCAT to put the child categories in comma separated lists with one row per parent category.

```
select 
    p.CategoryId as ParentCategoryId, 
    p.CategoryName as ParentCategoryName,
    c.CategoryId as CategoryId, 
    c.CategoryName as CategoryName 
from Categories c
JOIN Categories p
ON c.ParentCategoryId = p.CategoryId

select 
    p.CategoryId as ParentCategoryId, 
    p.CategoryName as ParentCategoryName,
    GROUP_CONCAT(c.CategoryId) as CategoryIds, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(c.CategoryName) as CategoryNames
from Categories c
JOIN Categories p
ON c.ParentCategoryId = p.CategoryId
GROUP BY p.`CategoryId`
ORDER BY p.`CategoryId`
```

The output from the second query:

```
ParentCategoryId    |   ParentCategoryName  |   CategoryIds |   CategoryNames
1   |   abc |   2,3 |   abc1,abc2
4   |   def |   5,6 |   def1,def2
7   |   ghi |   9,8 |   ghi2,ghi1
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this solve your problem,

```
;WITH cte 
     AS (SELECT p.categoryid   AS ParentCategoryId, 
                p.categoryname AS ParentCategoryName, 
                c.categoryid   AS CategoryId, 
                c.categoryname AS CategoryName 
         FROM   Categories  c 
                JOIN Categories  p 
                  ON c.parentcategoryid = p.categoryid) 
SELECT DISTINCT ParentCategoryId, 
                ParentCategoryName, 
                Stuff((SELECT ',' + Cast(t1.categoryid AS VARCHAR(10)) 
                       FROM   cte t1 
                       WHERE  t.parentcategoryid = t1.parentcategoryid 
                       FOR xml path('')), 1, 1, '') AS CategoryId, 
                Stuff((SELECT ',' + t2.categoryname 
                       FROM   cte t2 
                       WHERE  t.parentcategoryid = t2.parentcategoryid 
                       FOR xml path('')), 1, 1, '') AS CategoryName 
FROM   cte t
```